# CDF player InputField list

Tags: cdf-format

I want to work with lists within the CDF player.
A very simple example, which works inside a notebook is

```
DynamicModule[{x = {1, 2, 7}}, 
 Panel[Column@{InputField[Dynamic@x, Expression], Dynamic@func@x}], 
 Initialization :> (func[x_] := 2*ToExpression[x])]
```

Exported as a stand alone CDF application this does not work.
Changing input `x` results in nothing!

If `x` is a Number then it works also in the CDF player.

Comment: From http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/details-for-mathematica-programmers.html : "Non-numeric input fields are not supported. Avoid InputField[x, String] and InputField[x, Boxes]. InputField[x, Expression] and InputField[x] are restricted to work only with numbers, and InputField[x, Number] works normally."

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to input lists of numbers, you can use a single `InputField` to select the length and generate one `InputField` per entry:

```
DynamicModule[{a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, m = 5},

{Row[{
  InputField[Dynamic[m], Expression, ImageSize -> 40],
   DynamicWrapper[
     Dynamic@Table[With[{i = i}, 
        InputField[Dynamic[a[[i]]], ImageSize -> 30]]
     , {i, 1, m}]
   , If[Length@a =!= Round@m, a = PadRight[a[[1 ;; Min[m, Length[a]]]], m]]]
 }], Dynamic[a]}
 ]
```

Now the user can change the length of the list, and the elements of it:

[image: The resulting interactive list generator]

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But mostly I would need a list of tuples or
so. E.g.
{{a,b,2},{r,f,3},...}
I think this would be rather difficult to realize?!

Comment: @perit Your example ("E.g.") contains nonnumeric expressions (a, b, r, f) which are not supported, no matter how one tries to program the ability to enter the components of lists.