# A bug in InputField of type Expression?

Tags: dynamic, interface, inputfield, input, cdfplayer

I have a problem with a simple `InputField` of type `Expression`:

```
DynamicModule[{inputExpr = {{{1, 2}, {4, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}} , result = ""},
 Column[{Style["Input:", 12, Blue, Editable -> False],
   InputField[Dynamic[inputExpr], Expression, BaseStyle -> {"Input", 12}, 
    ImageSize -> 500],
   Button[Style["Calculate", 12, Red, Bold, Editable -> False],
    result = inputExpr^2, ImageSize -> 500],
   Style["Result:", 12, Red, Editable -> False],
   Framed[Dynamic[result], BaseStyle -> {12, PrintPrecision -> 3}, ImageSize -> 500]}, 
  Alignment -> Left]]
```

> [image: output]

When I input a different expression than the default, I get an error when I press the "Calculate" button:

[image: screen recording]

What am I doing wrong? How to create a working input field of `Expression` type? Note, that **I need to run it within the free CDF Player**, which has some limitations for `InputField`.

I tried to use the type `Boxes` instead of `Expression` (as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202758/280)), and it works in the full *Mathematica*, but not in the  free CDF Player.

Comment: An old partial duplicate without a solution: "[CDF player InputField list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18817/280)."

Comment: I seems to work if you don't set the BaseStyle to Input. Maybe since Input is a cell style, this triggers some box-related computation to occur.

Comment: Although what "work" means needs to be clarifies. It seems that if the input isn't a valid expression, then it's interpreted as a string. Maybe that's acceptable?

Comment: @lericr Yes, that's acceplable. But I need to run it in the free CDF player.

Comment: I haven't used the CDF player. Is it restricted to "read only" usage, i.e. one can't input new Mathematica expressions? If so, maybe this has more to do with constraints being imposed in the CDF player than with the behavior of InputField?

Comment: @lericr Yes, now I understand that the problem is with the limitations of the free version. OK, without Player Pro it is impossible to create even `InputField` of the `String` type. So I will accept an answer showing at least how to achieve my goal with the full *Mathematica* (I wish to have the `"Input"`-like automatic formatting withing the `InputField`).

Comment: Can't comment more time atm but are closely related topics: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199972/5478

Comment: @Kuba I've found that setting `FormatType -> StandardForm` also solves the problem, see my answer. I'm not completely sure whether the default option `FormatType -> InputForm` of the `"Input"` style is a bug or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, [lericr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/84894/lericr) is [correct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274044/a-bug-in-inputfield-of-type-expression/274060#comment684210_274044) that the problem appears only when I specify the `"Input"` style in the `BaseStyle` of `InputField`. Removing this makes the code working in the full *Mathematica*. The immediate source of the problem is the option `FormatType -> InputForm` included in the `"Input"` style. Adding the option `FormatType -> StandardForm` to the `BaseStyle` of `InputField` also works:

```
BaseStyle -> {"Input", 12, FormatType -> StandardForm}
```

Alternatively, one can use `Boxes` instead of `Expression` as in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199973/280) answer and keep just the `"Input"` style. This also works in the full *Mathematica*.

To reproduce the styling of the input cells more closely, one can also add the `"Notebook"` style and the options `ShowCodeAssist -> True, ShowSyntaxStyles -> True` as in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199973/280) answer:

```
BaseStyle -> {"Notebook", "Input", 12, FormatType -> StandardForm,
              ShowCodeAssist -> True, ShowSyntaxStyles -> True}
```

As to why all these solutions don't work in the free CDF Player, the following [comment](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/146598) by [Christopher Wolfram](https://community.wolfram.com/web/christopher) explains the situation:

> CDF does not allow input fields because if you could you could create a free version of Mathematica using the CDF player.

I wasn't able to find an information about the limitations of the free CDF/Wolfram Player on the official site, but [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) cites it in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18817/cdf-player-inputfield-list#comment56825_18817) under an older question:

> Non-numeric input fields are not supported. Avoid `InputField[x, String]` and `InputField[x, Boxes]`. `InputField[x, Expression]` and `InputField[x]` are restricted to work only with numbers, and `InputField[x, Number]` works normally.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have made some progress with the following changes:

```
(* Make inputExpr a string *)
inputExpr = "{{{1, 2}, {4, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}"

(* Set the type of InputField to String *)
InputField[
    Dynamic[inputExpr],
    String, (* <--- *)
    BaseStyle -> {"Input", 12},
    ImageSize -> 500
]

(* Change result to the following *)
result = ToExpression[inputExpr]^2
```

There might be a bug with `InputField` set to type `Expression`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work within the free CDF player. A better workaround with `Boxes` instead of `Expression` also doesn't work.